# Is Nodemailer a free api/library?

Tags: node.js, email, html-email, nodemailer

Is Nodemailer a free api/library?
If it is not free, where can I see the price. How is it different from the free version?

I am looking for (free) library or api to send email (company (not gmail) to customer)

Comment: How about looking on the [website for Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its an opensource library with MIT license.

There is no paid version for this library - but you can donate. May be you should use the library and donate for what it gives you.

The donate button is located at the bottom left corner -

https://nodemailer.com/about/